# Picard-Lindelöf vs $y'=\sqrt{y}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have a very simple ODE:

\begin{align*}
  y' &= \sqrt{y}
\end{align*}

One of the corollaries of Picard-Lindelöf theorem is that if one has $y' = f(x,y)$ and $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are continuous on some rectangle containing $(x_0, y_0)$,  then the solution passing through $(x_0,y_0)$ is unique. However, if i pick $(x_0,y_0)=(2,1)$, both $\sqrt{y}$ and $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y}}$ are continuous for $y$ in any band that is strictly in the positive semi-plane $y>0$, yet, I get two solutions passing through that point, specifically: $y_1(x) = \left( \frac{x}{2}\right)^2$ and $y_2(x) = \left( \frac{x-4}{2}\right)^2$. What is going on here?

Comment: $\sqrt{y_2(x)}= |x-4|/2 =(4-x)/2$ for $x $ near $2$, and $y_2'(x)=(x-4)/2$. So $y_2$ is not a solution.

Comment: @Gerd This doesn't really answer the question though, since the same problem occurs for any $y_a(x) = \left(\frac{x+a}{2}\right)^2$ with $a>0$ and your approach doesn't provide an answer in those cases

Comment: @StiftungWarentest If $a>0$ how do you manage to pass through the same point $(x_0,y_0)$?

Comment: you are right, my bad